# Why is $ (\frac{1}{0} )$ not defined?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is $ (\frac{a}{0} ), a \in R $ not defined?

if :$a=0$ what?

Comment: It is an assumption

Comment: Siri has a [fun answer](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2015/06/30/ask-siri-what-is-zero-divided-by-zero-and-she-will-send-you-to-the-burn-ward/) to this question.

Comment: I answered that question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751303/is-there-an-answer-to-1-0/1751313#1751313), and I'm certain it's been asked many times even before then. Basically, if you want your multiplication to be reasonable, and division to be the inverse of multiplication, then $\frac a0$ cannot be assigned a value in any consistent way.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to know one thing:

> *What does "$\frac{a}{m}$" mean*?

*The answer is*: "$a/m$ is the **one and only unique** solution to the equation $mr = a$." ($r$ is the unknown that I have considered).

Given that, let's consider the case under consideration:

For $m=0$, the equation clearly states that it has no solutions: for something to be equal to $\frac{a}{0}$, with $a\neq 0$, we would need $0\cdot r = a$. But $0\cdot r = 0$ for any $r$, so there are *no* solutions to the equation and since there are no unique solutions to the equation, there is no such thing as $\frac{a}{0}$. So $\frac{a}{0}$ does *not* represent any mathematical number.

Rigorously speaking, we simply do not define "division by $0$" for real analysis.

Answer (score 0):

By $R$, I assume that you mean the real numbers $\mathbb R$.

Let's think about what division means.

We know that $14 \div 7 = 2$ because you add $7$ together twice to get $14$, i.e. $7 \times 2 = 14$.

We know that $100 \div 5 = 20$ because you add $5$ together twenty times to get $100$, i.e. $20 \times 5 = 100$

What about $1 \div 0$? How many times do you add zero together to get one? Solve $0 \times x = 1$.

You can't do it. It doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting variation is the following: In commutative algebra, if you are allowed fractions (via the construction known as localisation), then you are always allowed to expand a fraction by any number that is a valid denominator. Within that framework, if you allow $0$ as a valid denominator, you automatically say that any fraction may be expanded by $0$. If we take an arbitrary fraction $\frac ab$, and use that, we get
$$
\frac{a}{b} = \frac{0\cdot a}{0\cdot b} = \frac{0}{0}
$$
which means that *every single number* is equal to $\frac00$. That's kind of boring, don't you think?